# React : Take input file when link is clicked in function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and javascript want to create a link with name "Browse" which when clicked should take file as input , i got many answers to do it inside class component in React, how can i do it in function component . I tried:

```
<div>
     <br /><span>{i18n.gettext('- or - ')}</span>
     <input id='logo-input' ref='logoInput' type='file' onChange={onFileSelected} type='hidden' />
     <a href='' onClick={handleBrowse}>{ i18n.gettext('Browse')}</a>
     <br />
</div>
```

handleBrowse function:

```
const handleBrowse = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.refs.logoInput.click();
    };
```

onFileSelected function:

```
const onFileSelected = function (e) {
        const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.currentTarget.files[0];
        handleFileSelection(file);
    };
```

when i do it , i get error as:

```
Stateless function components cannot have refs
```

I understood that function component cannot have refs, how can i implement this then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you rewrite your component as a class, maybe this error will be gone

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component{

    handleBrowse =(e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.refs.logoInput.click();
    };

    onFileSelected = (e) => {
        const file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.currentTarget.files[0];
        handleFileSelection(file);
    };

  render(){
     return (
       <div>
         <br /><span>{i18n.gettext('- or - ')}</span>
         <input id='logo-input' ref='logoInput' type='file' onChange={onFileSelected} type='hidden' />
         <a href='' onClick={this.handleBrowse}>{ i18n.gettext('Browse')}</a>
       <br />
      </div>
     )
  }
}
```

As a stateless component, this should work like this :

```
const App = ()=>{

  let myref = null;

  const onFileSelected = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e)
  }

  const handleBrowse = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    myref.click();
  };

   return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
        <input id='logo-input' ref={(r) => {myref=r}} type='file' onChange={onFileSelected} />
        <a onClick={handleBrowse}>{ i18n.gettext('Browse')}</a>
      </div>
    );

}
```

Comment: probably will have to do it, but as it is in prod want to try it with minimal change, not worried about error want if could be done in any other way in function component

Comment: Perfect, Thanks